# Android: Can I access system services without an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, accelerometer, sensors

I have been reading and have seen that system services cannot be accessed straight away; they must be accessed after onCreate() has been called.

I am creating a Keyboard service but I would like to access system services such as sensors. Is there a way I can do this without an activity?

I have already tried having my class inheriting InputMethodService and implementing SensorEventListener. I implement the method onSensorChanged() and tell it to print to logcat but it is never called. I have a method onCreateInputView() in which I define the sensor manager and accelerometer:

```
public class MyInput extends InputMethodService implements SensorEventListener {
    MyInputView MyInputView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        final MyInputView MyInputView = (MyInputView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.MyInput, null);

        this.MyInputView = MyInputView;

        return MyInputView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("called", "called");
    }

}
```

[Based on suggestions given it appears InputMethodService derives from Context and as such, onCreate() *should* be called...]

Comment: Interesting question.  InputMethodService also inherits from Context, so the getSystemService() method should at least exist, and it has an onCreate() lifecycle method.  What happens if you try to obtain the service you want using this Context after onCreate() has been called?

Comment: Ok, so where is the code that is setting up for updates, and the event method which is not firing?  At this point the collective belief seems to be that what you want to do is *possible* therefore the problem is with your attempt, and we can't help with that without seeing exactly what you are trying to do to get *just this* working.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Attached is what I'm dealing with

Comment: read the doc. getSystemService is a method from Context. Any properly initialized (i.e. activity or service after they are started) will do.

Comment: @njzk2 I have read the docs and I have initialised the service as shown.

Comment: you never call `mSensorManager.registerListener` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to not only obtain your service, but also register your event listener.

See for example the following section from the ApiDemos project of the (legacy) SDK Samples:

```
 mSensorManager.registerListener(mGraphView, 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER | 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_MAGNETIC_FIELD | 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

In your case it is your MyInput class itself which implements the event listener, so you would pass your instance of that instead.

Comment: Damn it, I knew it'd be something simple... Thanks very much for taking the time to spot this!

Answer (score 3):

`getSystemService()` can be called on any instance of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), and since [InputMethodService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html) traces its origins back to Context, you can obtain access to system services in it, as long as your call is after the `onCreate()` method.

This works just like when you use the Accelerometer from a background service. Having a visible Activity is not a requirement for getting access to system Services.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I want to do. I want to access the accelerometer. However, how can you be sure that onCreate() has been called?

Comment: @mino You can set a boolean flag in the method body of your onCreate implementation. But generally, if your system service access is inside a method body in your InputMethodService, it will be called after onCreate (unless it is a static method being called from outside)

Comment: This still does not seem to work. I have my class inheriting InputMethodService and implementing SensorEventListener. I implement the method onSensorChanged() and tell it to print to logcat but it is never called.

Comment: Then you should probably put that in your question, along with a minimal (tested!) version of the code.  Right now, it seems you are asking if you can even obtain the system service, and unless you are getting a null result from that call, it seems like you can.